# Generate orm.yml mapping file from existing entity file in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is there a way to generate `src\AppBundle\Resources\Config\doctrine\example.orm.yml` file from an existing entity file `src\AppBundle\Entity\Example.php`, rather than use `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity` to create a new entity?

Comment: This is such a useful feature for Symfony, however I was surprised to learn that Doctrine is removing this feature altogether soon!  "...this feature to generate entities from existing databases will be completely removed in the next Doctrine version."
https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Answer (score 1):

To Generate this file, you need something that doctrine can use to do it.

So if you have your database already up, you can do a

```
    php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import
```

but if you want to do it "code first", i guess you need to create the mapping information yourself and then use

```
    app/console generate:doctrine:entities <Your Bundle>
    app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
    app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: thanks, yes there's always the option to make an orm.yml file manually but I was hoping there was a command that converted an existing entity php file  to a orm.yml file (with no db table existing before that)

Comment: if your entity already have mapping informations (annotations), you can try
 `app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml `